# Add a field with custom attribute depending on number of fields

Tags: javascript, input, custom-attribute

I need some help with js - im too noobish in it to figure how to do what I need. Searched for solution but it seems that my issue is quite specific.
Right now I got a form with several fields and a button, that add one more field.

But I need not just another field, but a field with custom "name" and "placeholder" parameters, that depend on the number of the existing fields. Like if there are three fields, I need the function to create field with placeholder="Field 4" and name="start4".

Thanks for any help in advance!

Here's my code

```js
function add_fields() {
    
   var d = document.getElementById("fields");
  
   d.innerHTML += "<label>Field #</label><br /><input  type='text' class='start1' name='start#' placeholder='Field #'/><br />";
}
```

```html
<form action="" style="text-align: center;" method="get">

<div id="fields">
    <label>Field 1</label><br />
    <input  type="text" class="start1" name="start1" placeholder="Field 1"/><br />
    <label>Field 2</label><br />
    <input  type="text" class="start1" name="start2" placeholder="Field 2"/><br />
    <label>Field 3</label><br />
    <input  type="text" class="start1" name="start3" placeholder="Field 3"/><br />
</div>
<a class="button" onClick="add_fields()">Add field</a>

<input type="hidden" name="step" value="2"/><br /><br />
<input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know ahead of time how many fileds you will have you can just count the existing ones instead of using a counter.

```
function add_fields() {
   var count= document.querySelectorAll("#fields input").length + 1; 
   var d = document.getElementById("fields");
   d.innerHTML += "<label>Field "+count+"</label><br /><input  type='text' class='start"+count+"' name='start"+count+"' placeholder='Field "+count+"'/><br />";
   return false;
}
```

[Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/c5gro7f6/1/)

[Don't forget to return false in the function or else your link will be submitted!]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data-*` attribute for counter if you want. Please get the value by `getAttribute("data-*")` in JS.

Moreover, you can use DOM Elements to edit html view.

HTML

```
<form action="" style="text-align: center;" method="get">
  <div id="fields" data-fields="3">
    <label for="field-1">Field 1</label><br />
    <input id="field-1" type="text" class="start1" name="start1" placeholder="Field 1"/><br />
    <label for="field-2">Field 2</label><br />
    <input id="field-2" type="text" class="start1" name="start2" placeholder="Field 2"/><br />
    <label for="field-3">Field 3</label><br />
    <input id="field-3" type="text" class="start1" name="start3" placeholder="Field 3"/><br />
  </div>

  <a class="button" onClick="add_fields()">Add field</a>

  <input type="hidden" name="step" value="2"/><br />
  <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

JS

```
function add_fields() {
  var field = document.getElementById("fields");
  var index = Number(field.getAttribute("data-fields")) + 1;

  var newLabel = document.createElement("label");
  var newField = document.createElement("input");
  var breakrow1 = document.createElement("br");
  var breakrow2 = document.createElement("br");

  newLabel.setAttribute("for", "field-" + index);
  newLabel.textContent = "Field " + index;

  newField.id = "field-" + index;
  newField.type = "text";
  newField.className = "start1";
  newField.name = "start" + index;
  newField.placeholder = "Field " + index;

  field.appendChild(newLabel);
  field.appendChild(breakrow1);
  field.appendChild(newField);
  field.appendChild(breakrow2);
  field.setAttribute("data-fields", index);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are on the right track, just add a global counter and use it to name the fields on `add_fields` function call:

```
var counter = 4; // starting with 4
function add_fields() {    
  var d = document.getElementById("fields");

  d.innerHTML += "<label>Field #</label><br /><input  type='text' class='start1' name='start" + counter + "' placeholder='Field " + counter + "'/><br />";
  counter++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped!